# Children's illustrated book about a Masai warrior and a lion

Tags: identification-request

When I was a child in the late eighties, my local library had an illustrated book. I was four to five years old and barely remember it, but I know it was really important to me at that age (I kept asking to borrow it every time we went) and eventually my mother bought it when the library was going to throw it out. Sadly it was lost later, and I am seeking to find out what it might have been.

Description:

- Late eighties (1987-1990) in Australia
- The book was, at the end of that time, decommissioned from the library and sold secondhand, meaning it was quite old and worn. So the book itself might have been from the 1960s onwards. It was presumably a popular children's book!
- The book was suitable for my age, and I must have been three to five years old. Large text, not much text, big illustrations
- I remember it being set in Africa, there being a lion, and a Masai warrior. I don't recall the story but I do *not* remember it being violent (eg attacking the lion.) I am not sure if the lion was a character though - I think it was more a 'realistic' story.
- It was a large-size children's book: I have a child's memory of it, but you know how some illustrated books are the size of, say, a modern large-ish screen, ie open up to the size a large-ish laptop opens up? That sort of size.
- I don't recall the illustration style, other than maybe pencil, paint, etc. "Drawn" not, say, paper cutouts or something. Fairly pastel colours?
- It was in English, but no idea if that was the original language.

A long shot -- but many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

*The Lion's Tail* by Douglas F. Davis perhaps.

I could only find picture of the cover in [Ebony Jr.,05 1981](https://books.google.com/books?id=f8QDAAAAMBAJ):
[image: cover image]

> Even today the Masai people of Africa are known as great cattle
> herders. This exciting folktale tells how the Masai came to greatness
> after receiving the "divine gift" of cattle from the god Ngai, long,
> long, ago. Follow along as the Masai battle the plains lions and their
> strong leader Tambu for the right to keep the cattle. . The Masai
> hunter Ndangaio leads the warriors in outwitting the lion people time
> after time. In the end Ndangaio's plan teaches Tambu a very painful
> lesson, one that remains with the lion to this very day.